# link for free data base contains all words in English?

Tags: database, words

Can anyone give me link for free data base contains all words in English?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using http://wordnet.princeton.edu/ WordNet® is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept. Synsets are interlinked by means of conceptual-semantic and lexical relations. http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/license/